# Does AppCode support parameter list completion for Swift?

Tags: swift, appcode

Hitting CTRL-p or Cmd-p doesn't bring up a list of all the parameters. So I suppose it doesn't. But it does seem to be supported for Objective-C. Perhaps I'm missing something? Is there a button to activate it?

Answer (score 2):

[Cmd+P should be available](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11351) in the next 3.1.x update

Comment: When is that one due?

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When you close XCode, execute

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
```

and re-open XCode it works better for a couple of minutes. XCode 6 (and Swift) are late Alpha version. SourceKit crashes every 2 minutes....

Comment: Judging from the title and the tags, the question was about AppCode, not Xcode.

Comment: Ups. Seems my brain had auto-correct turned on ;-) So forget my answer (except you switch to XCode :)